# Trying to parse Word docx file as a zip document using Python's xml.elementtree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I'm trying to parse a Windows docx file as a zip file using Python's xml.elementtree module.  I saved the docx file as a zip.  Below is what the document looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
-<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
-<pkg:part pkg:padding="512" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-  package.relationships+xml" pkg:name="/_rels/.rels">
+<pkg:xmlData>
</pkg:part>
+<pkg:part pkg:padding="256" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels">
-<pkg:part pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml" pkg:name="/word/document.xml">
-<pkg:xmlData>
-<w:document   xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
-<w:body>
-<w:p w:rsidP="00E65A71" w:rsidRDefault="00E65A71" w:rsidR="00E65A71">
-<w:r>
 <w:t>Gloss:</w:t>
 </w:r>
 -<w:r>
 <w:tab/>
 </w:r>
-<w:r w:rsidRPr="00EC6528">
-<w:rPr>
 <w:noProof/>
 </w:rPr>
 <w:t>the door</w:t>
 </w:r>
 </w:p>
-<w:p w:rsidP="00E65A71" w:rsidRDefault="00E65A71" w:rsidR="00E65A71">
-<w:r>
 <w:t xml:space="preserve">Base: </w:t>
 </w:r>
-<w:r>
 <w:tab/>
 </w:r>
-<w:r w:rsidRPr="00EC6528">
-<w:rPr>
 <w:noProof/>
 </w:rPr>
 <w:t>words</w:t>
 </w:r>
-<w:r>
```

As you can see I've minimized a few of the elements to save space.  I'm interested in the stuff in the

```
<w:document><w:body>
```

elements specifically:

```
<w:r><w:t>
```

that's where the data is that I want to parse.  I can't seem to get past the first element.  Below is what's tried to get at that stuff:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('document.xml')
body = tree.getroot().findall("w")
#body = tree.getroot().findall(w:t)
#body = tree.getroot()
```

and also:

```
for child in root:
   print child.tag, child.attrib
```

I've tried that just to see if I could see any of the elements I could then drill into but that returns nothing.  I've also tried other code but I can't seem to get to the stuff I want.  I've programmed a lot in Python put never used this module to parse XML.  I'm using VS studio 2012 with pytools and when I set a breakpoint and look at the "root" structure I can't seem to drill into the element I want to get.  I can't seem to navigate past the "pkg:package" stuff.  My end goal is to set up a for loop to work through the "" stuff that will be repeated throughout the document.  I've been researching this for a little while and trying to work through a few of the tutorials so any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Open Office Xml (which is the standard that Microsoft uses for its newer Office software), the letter in front of the colon in the tag is a prefix and requires a particular namespace mapping to be processed correctly. For instance, the tag <w:t> actually requires you to search for the tag string "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}t". The prefix/namespace is surrounded by curly brackets and the actual tag name follows at the end. Fortunately, most of what you're probably looking for uses the namespace that I mentioned above. Here's some sample code that should get you started in the right direction:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# I find that using a dictionary to map prefixes to namespaces keeps
# things easier to understand. You can also use the namespaces directly
# though if you prefer
NAMESPACE_PREFIXES = {
    'w': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
    }  

tree = ET.parse('document.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
text_elements = [element for element in root.iter() if element.tag == 
'{' + NAMESPACE_PREFIXES['w'] + '}t']
# Equivalent to:
# text_elements = [element for element in root.iter() if element.tag == 
# '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}t']
for text_element in text_elements:
    if text_element.text == 'Hello world!':
        text_element.text = 'Goodbye world!'
```

[Here](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/ooxml/) are some additional namespaces for OOXML in case you need them as well.